# Labeling unlabeled data (expectation maximization)

Tags: expectation-maximization, labeling

Say I have a database (Excel) consisting of 10k different dresses and accompanying attributes (column names) for each dress (sleeve length, color, pattern, ...). I would like to label each of these dresses with a level of formality (e.g. 0 very casual, 1 'neutral', 2 very formal), so adding a new column for each dress. However, doing this manually is very time-consuming, therefore I was looking into EM algorithms.

I understood that it's possible to estimate such labels by first manually labeling a couple of dresses and then use EM to label the rest. For example, the algorithm would be able to pick up that a new "knee length dress" is very likely to be "very formal" if I've previously labeled all my knee length dresses of my training set as "very formal". Is this correct? Or are there other algorithms that are better suited? And to follow up: can I do this using Python?

Comment: In what form do you have all these dresses? Images? Textual descriptions?

Comment: Excel file, of which the column titels are: url --- color --- sleeve length --- pattern --- etc. @kjetil b halvorsen

Comment: Please add that description to your Q as an edit, maybe post a few lines of the file as an example!